# Is asking questions about a particular data set on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is asking questions about a particular data set on-topic on this Stack Exchange?

E.g.:

> Title: Fillers in the ICSI Meeting Recorder Dialog Act (MRDA) Corpus
>
> Body: In the [ICSI Meeting Recorder Dialog Act (MRDA) Corpus](http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/Speech/mr/), which label(s) correspond to the Filler class?
>
> I have read a couple of article (e.g. (1)) saying there exist a widely applied classmap that maps the dialog acts onto 5 distinct classes: statements (S), questions (Q), backchannels (B), fillers (F) and disruptions (D).
>
> However, looking at the data set official manual (2) and paper (3), I fail to see which label(s) should be regarded as fillers:
>
> [image]
>
> (1) Verbree, Daan, Rutger Rienks, and Dirk Heylen. "[Dialogue-act tagging using smart feature selection; results on multiple corpora.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=2215828925874010278&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22)" Spoken Language Technology Workshop, 2006. IEEE. IEEE, 2006.
>   APA
>
> Dhillon, Rajdip, et al. [Meeting recorder project: Dialog act labeling guide](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=14701314755480463137&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22). No. ICSI-TR-04-002. INTERNATIONAL COMPUTER SCIENCE INST BERKELEY CA, 2004.
>
> (3) Shriberg, E., et al., “[The ICSI Meeting Recorder Dialog Act
>   (MRDA) Corpus](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=5772938544285889197&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22)” Proc. SIGDIAL, Cambridge, MA, April-May 2004.

Comment: IMO, it's on-topic. Shall I migrate it to the main site?

Comment: @prash Not sure if it's convenient: first, we'd have to edit the question since this one is "Meta", and also, keeping it here will allow future visitors to see that questions like this one are allowed (or not, in case the question is not). I'd leave this question here and ask Franck to post it again on the main site.

Comment: @prash thanks, done: [Fillers in the ICSI Meeting Recorder Dialog Act (MRDA) Corpus](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/15380/2680)

Comment: @prash by the way you are welcome to convert your comment into an answer so that I can accept it and other people can vote on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be on-topic, but if no one else is familiar with that data set, be prepared to wait a very long time for answers ;)